# scatterplot3d for response surface in R

Tags: r, graph, scatter-plot

I want to graph response surface through scatterplot3d but the following code through an error.

```
library(rsm)
swiss2.lm <- lm(Fertility ~ poly(Agriculture, Education, degree = 2), data = swiss)
persp(swiss2.lm, Education ~ Agriculture, zlab = "Fertility")

library(scatterplot3d)
s3d <- 
  scatterplot3d(
      swiss
   # , type = "h"
    , highlight.3d = TRUE
    , angle = 55
    , scale.y = 0.7
    , pch = 16
     )

s3d$plane3d(swiss2.lm, lty.box = "solid")
```

How can I figure out the issue?

### Edit

```
Error in segments(x, z1, x + y.max * yx.f, z2 + yz.f * y.max, lty = ltya,  : 
  cannot mix zero-length and non-zero-length coordinates
```

I'm using `swiss` data from `rsm` library.

Comment: What error? What data are you using?

Comment: @JeffAllen: See my edits. Thasnks

Comment: @MYaseen208 I don't know if this can help but if you run poly with degree= 1 , you don' have the error. swiss2.lm <- lm(Fertility ~ poly(Agriculture, Education, degree = **1**), data = swiss)

Comment: Thanks @agstudy for your comment and showing interest in my problem. Actually I need second degree polynomial so degree should be 2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How attached are you to using `scatterplot3d`?  If you're willing to do it in `rgl` it's pretty easy.  Following from your example:

Set up evenly spaced grid and make predictions:

```
newdat <- expand.grid(Education=seq(0,50,by=5),
            Agriculture=seq(0,100,by=10))
newdat$pp <- predict(swiss2.lm,newdata=newdat)
```

Plot points and add surface:

```
library(rgl)
with(swiss,plot3d(Agriculture,Education,Fertility))
with(newdat,surface3d(unique(Agriculture),unique(Education),pp,
                      alpha=0.3,front="line"))
rgl.snapshot("swiss.png")
```

[image]

`rgl` has some advantages (hidden line removal, lighting effects, dynamic rotation and zooming) and some disadvantages (doesn't fit well into base-package layouts etc.; harder to manipulate fonts, include `plotmath` equations, etc.; harder to adjust label placement and plot style).  The `scatter3d` function in the `car` package has some nice features for adding regression surfaces to an `rgl` plot, but as far as I can see it does additive models, but doesn't allow for quadratic polynomial models ...

As far as I can see, in order to do this in the `scatterplot3d` framework you would have to construct the points corresponding to the quadrangles in the regression surface and use `xyz.convert` and `segments` to draw them ...